# How can I access youtube playlistitem without authorization(oauth 2.0)?

Tags: youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to retrieve the a JSON object containing the video information for all the uploads on a single YouTube channel using the YouTube Data API v.3. In the examples I've come across, I see they first create a YouTube object with some sort of authorization (if I'm understanding the Auth object correctly), possibly because in those examples they're performing a request where they wanted to access each particular user's YouTube channel's videos:

```
[...]

import com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.Auth;

[...]

// This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows for full read/write access to the
// authenticated user's account.
List<String> scopes = Lists.newArrayList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube");

try {
    // Authorize the request.
    Credential credential = Auth.authorize(scopes, "playlistupdates");

    // This object is used to make YouTube Data API requests.
    youtube = new YouTube.Builder(Auth.HTTP_TRANSPORT, Auth.JSON_FACTORY, credential)
            .setApplicationName("youtube-cmdline-playlistupdates-sample")
            .build();
```

I can't figure out if there's a way to build this YouTube object to access the other methods in the API without requiring the OAuth authorization when routinely requesting video information from one particular channel and not channels from each particular user that utilizes the application.

what arguments the Builder method takes, but I don't know what parameters to add if not the ones added above. Am I wrong in assuming there's a way to access the API without having some OAuth authorization (that is, requiring a user login)?

Comment: Is this a public play list you are looking to access?

Comment: actually i want to access the publish time of videos present in a user subscribed channel. To do so youtube api provides playlistitem.list() method. However,i already have stored the user's channels in my database,so now i want to perform a general access of those channels as i have already retieved their credentials like channel id and upload id.

Comment: yes it is contained in a public channel.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `channelId` to get the videos for a channel via request to the `search` endpoint, which does not require oauth:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=ID&key=KEY